# Android - How to programmatically set the color of the icon of an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to use the same icon (which is a `vector`) with various colors by programmatically setting its color as we do thanks to the `android:tint` property.

Here is the `builder` that sets the icon of `AlertDialog`:

```
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
```

Is there a way to do that? Do we have to create the same icon again if we just want to use it with a different color?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `ImageView` and set the `ColorFilter`. try the code below. See if it works as expected.

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DemoActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Message");
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            ImageView imageView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
            if (imageView != null)
                imageView.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Not worked for a custom color. When I use `BLUE` as the color it has worked. But when I try to use a custom color (`#fbcb97`) which is defined in my `colors.xml`, a different color is displayed instead of the expected one.

Comment: I have tested it on Android O with your color code and it worked. It seems little bit more alpha but i think thats because the color itself has it. On which version you are testing it ?

Comment: The hex code of the color I have retrieved through the taken screenshot is `#838093`. Testing on `API Level 26`.